# Advantage of using tabbarcontroller instead of tab bar and tab bar item

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

This may be a completely meaningless question, but I got lost. Why should one use tabbarcontroller instead of using tab bar and tab bar items?

As can be seen in the image, I can put a Tab Bar and Tab Bar Items inside a root view, so why should I use tabbarcontroller?

[image]

Comment: In the former you're on your own to setup and manage the contained view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You use a `UITabBarController` when you want a simple way to switch between different view controllers using a tab bar.

You use a `UITabBar` when you want your own custom behavior attached to the tab bar.

Answer (score 0):

A view (UITabbar) object knows how to display data to a user and accept user input. UITabBar is a subclass of UIView, display a list of tabs items to the user, and how to display feedback to the user when the user interacts with the tabs. UITabItems are similar to any other UIElements but specially designed to be used within UITabbar due to the unique design and property such as badges.

A controller (UITabbarController) object that knows what data to display to a user and what to do with user input.  A UITabBarController is a subclass of UIViewController, It knows what tabs to display to the user, and what to do when the user chooses a tab. This class acts as a convenient base class from which you can derive your controller and also has property's that make it easier to reference when developing.